# Getting 403 and Cannot Create simple Web Service

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, c#-4.0, service

I have been tasked to write a simple webs service that validates requests and ensures they are valid before another team adds the methods in.

I am following this example >

I also followed a similar one earlier > http://www.csharptutorial.in/39/csharp-net-how-to-create-a-webservice-in-csharp-net-visual-studio-2010

However when I run "debug" all I get is this

Server Error in '/' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not create type 'PDRProWebService.PDRProWebService'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="PDRProWebService.asmx.cs" Class="PDRProWebService.PDRProWebService" %>

Source File: /PDRProWebService.asmx    Line: 1

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237

If I run it in "Release Mode" I get a 403 e.g

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Most likely causes:
A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Things you can try:
If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
Enable directory browsing.
Go to the IIS Express install directory.
Run appcmd set config /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the server level.
Run appcmd set config ["SITE_NAME"] /section:system.webServer/directoryBrowse /enabled:true to enable directory browsing at the site level.
Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

It talks about creating a default documwent for the website in IIS. However there is no mention of that in the tutorial.

I just need to get a skeleton service running so I can then add my methods etc.

is there a better tutorial for VS 2012 somewhere or am I missing something - even though I have followed the example line for line (apart from the name of the webservice)

The code is just

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace PDRProWebService
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Summary description for PDRProWebService
   /// </summary>
   [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
   [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
   [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
   // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the  following line. 
   //[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
   public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
   {

       [WebMethod]
       public string HelloWorld()
       {
            return "Hello World";
       }

       [WebMethod]
       public String MyFirstWebMethod(String firstName, String lastName)
      {
            //return “How are you ” + firstName + ” ” + lastName + “?”;
            return String.Format("How are you {0} {1}?", firstName, lastName);
      }
   }
}
```

Should I be using WCF now for webservices or is this still okay and how do I fix it?

Comment: You're not using WCF, you're using ASMX, which is a legacy technology.  I'd recommend you dump this approach and either look at some [WCF Tutorials](https://www.bing.com/search?q=WCF+Tutorials&qs=n&form=QBLH&pq=wcf+tutorials&sc=8-12&sp=-1&sk=&ghc=1&cvid=95b4f6fef0964e6d932aecb65cdd3b09) or some [WebAPI Tutorials](https://www.bing.com/search?q=WebAPI+Tutorials&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=webapi+tutorials&sc=2-16&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=92c3a59627fd4f0aa15c78ef310ed926) so you're learning the current .NET implementations of web services.

Comment: what you can do is try your visual studio or application run in administrative mode and set directory browsing enabled through IIS(if its actually used)